# Drawing a Warped Circle in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to draw a circle on a football field image.
Firstly, I create a homography between some points in the image matching some hardcoded reference points in real life.
Then I draw a circle to an overlay (blank) image which is warped by said homography.

```
overlay = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(overlay, center, radius, (0,0,255), 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
overlay = cv2.warpPerspective(overlay, homography, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
```

However, the result warped circle is far from sharp.

[image: Warped Circle]

I've tried increasing the overlay image's dimensions (with both center and radius adjusted) and then resizing back after drawing the circle. It worked but didn't produce any substancial improvements.

How can I make it look sharper?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your interpolation flags, if you use nearest it will be sharp.

```
overlay = cv2.warpPerspective(overlay, homography, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Get the docs in ipython as follows:

```
cv2.warpPerspective?
Docstring:
warpPerspective(src, M, dsize[, dst[, flags[, borderMode[, borderValue]]]]) -> dst
.   @brief Applies a perspective transformation to an image.
.
.   The function warpPerspective transforms the source image using the specified matrix:
.
.   \f[\texttt{dst} (x,y) =  \texttt{src} \left ( \frac{M_{11} x + M_{12} y + M_{13}}{M_{31} x + M_{32} y + M_{33}} ,
.        \frac{M_{21} x + M_{22} y + M_{23}}{M_{31} x + M_{32} y + M_{33}} \right )\f]
.
.   when the flag #WARP_INVERSE_MAP is set. Otherwise, the transformation is first inverted with invert
.   and then put in the formula above instead of M. The function cannot operate in-place.
.
.   @param src input image.
.   @param dst output image that has the size dsize and the same type as src .
.   @param M \f$3\times 3\f$ transformation matrix.
.   @param dsize size of the output image.
.   @param flags combination of interpolation methods (#INTER_LINEAR or #INTER_NEAREST) and the
.   optional flag #WARP_INVERSE_MAP, that sets M as the inverse transformation (
.   \f$\texttt{dst}\rightarrow\texttt{src}\f$ ).
.   @param borderMode pixel extrapolation method (#BORDER_CONSTANT or #BORDER_REPLICATE).
.   @param borderValue value used in case of a constant border; by default, it equals 0.
.
.   @sa  warpAffine, resize, remap, getRectSubPix, perspectiveTransform
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

---

Another thing that may help is to pay attention to interpolation used by how you are viewing the image.  If you use matplotlib you can explicitly tell it what kind of interpolation to use, if you are using a regular image viewer than you may not be able to set it.  More pixels will make the antialiasing "look" better (as you noted), but if you zoom in you should still see some artifacts.  Here is a more complete example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

height = 600
width = 600
center = (300, 300)
radius = 40
image = np.zeros((720, 1080, 3), np.uint8)
homography = np.array([[2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
overlay = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(overlay, center, radius, (0,0,255), 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)
output = cv2.warpPerspective(overlay, homography, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

plt.imshow(overlay, interpolation='nearest')
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(output, interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: You may also want to change your line type: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf076ef45de481ac96e0ab3dc2c29a777

Comment: I'm sorry to say it didn't work. However I did manage to make it a lot better by increasing the blank image's dimensions without resizing it back, forcing me to calculate the homography with the bigger image.